# operation on tensor

Tags: abstract-algebra

[Tensor product of modules over non commutative rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2091423/490689)

I have a problem on operation, since I am the beginner, I am confused whether the subgroup K generated by one of generator $(x_1+x_2,y)-(x_1,y)-(x_2,y)$, cannot simply to $(0,-y)$(ie pointwise) does it is not direct product?
thanks a lot

if you have any misunderstanding, please tell me

Comment: You seem to be treating the pairs $(x,y)$ in this definition of $\otimes$ as if they were vectors. They are not vectors. They are free generators of a module, so there are no linear relations between them. Linear relations are introduced only when you take the quotient by $K$.