# Why does the exactness of a Koszul complex require commutativity?

Tags: solution-verification, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Most references on Koszul complexes seem to assume that the elements $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ live in a commutative ring or are central. It appears to me that the proof also works provided the weaker assumption that $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ commute with each other.
Confirmation, a reference, or pointing out an error would be greatly appreciated.

*Claim:*
Suppose $R$ is a ring which need-not be commutative and let $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in R$ be commuting elements such that whenever
$\lambda x_{i+1} \in (x_{1},\ldots,x_i) $
it follows that $\lambda $ is in the left ideal $(x_{1},\ldots,x_i)$. Then the Koszul complex defined by
$$\phi: \wedge^q R^n \to \wedge^{q-1}R^n : \lambda e_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_q} \mapsto \lambda \sum_j (-1)^{j-1} x_{i_j} e_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \widehat{e_{i_j}} \cdots\wedge e_{i_q}   $$
yields a free resolution for $R/(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

*Sketch:*

1. Observe the statement is obvious for $n = 1$. We proceed by induction.
2. Consider the following short exact sequence in Koszul complexes
   $$0 \to \wedge^\bullet R^{n-1} \to \wedge^\bullet R^n \to \wedge^\bullet R^{n-1}[-1]\to 0.$$
3. There is an induced long exact sequence in cohomology
   $$ H^q(\wedge^\bullet R^{n-1}) \to H^q(\wedge^\bullet R^{n}) \to H^{q-1}(\wedge^\bullet R^{n-1})$$
4. Combined with the induction hypothesis this shows $H^q(\wedge^\bullet R^{n}) = 0$ whenever $q-1 \neq 0$.
5. The remaining claim for $H^1(\wedge^\bullet R^{n})$ is immediate from the assumption on the $x_i$. QED.

Comment: What is $\wedge^k R^n$ when $R$ is noncommutative? (I can imagine that there is a reasonable definition, but I don't know one off the bat and I wouldn't vouch for its uniqueness.)

Comment: For the purpose of the proof let's take the left-module structure defined by $\wedge^k R^n = \oplus_{1\leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} R^n$ and mainly use the wedge product as convenient notation.

Comment: The canonicity is related to similar problems with the tensor product. (i.e. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091423/tensor-product-of-modules-over-non-commutative-rings).) 

For those purposes one would be forced to take at least one copy of $R^n$ as a right-module. Correspondingly, the multilinear maps in the canonical definition are right-linear in this component.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide more details. This is based on theorem 0.6 in [these notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/Math_250B-2016/Notes/koszul.pdf)

Comment: Why are you interested in this situation? The Koszul complex is interesting because it gives us resolutions of modules over commutative rings. In the non-commutative setting, the analog is called the Shafarevich complex, but non-commutativity will usually make things much more complicated. In general, you do have a Koszul complex available if you take a base ring and add commuting variables, though, I think this is what you are after?

Comment: I use this particular situation to establish a claim about a particular $\mathscr{D}_X$ module.

Comment: I could find a Koszul complex when the variables are in the center of the ring. The content of this question is whether it is sufficient if they are mutually commuting.